Issues with animation spacing/stretching in Beamer
I'm working on animating a red circle moving around a yellow circle in beamer, while simultaneously tracking the elapsed time, angle turned, and completed cycles. However, I'm encountering a few issues, notably:
I want the equals signs in the displayed text to align vertically for a cleaner appearance. All I can manage at the moment is to centre all the lines underneath the rotating circle.
I'm looking for a complete solution to this problem if possible.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{pgfmath} % For calculations
\usepackage{calc}    % For width calculations

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[fragile]
    \frametitle{Rotating Yellow Circle Example}
    \begin{columns}
      \begin{column}{0.50\textwidth}
        Text for signal description and other explanations. 
        
        Here is an animation of a yellow circle rotating about its center to demonstrate angular speed.
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{0.50\textwidth}\centering
        \begin{animateinline}[controls={play,stop,step},loop]{12}
          \multiframe{36}{i=0+10}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
              % Draw the rotating yellow circle
              \fill[yellow] (0,0) circle (0.5); % Circle at the origin
              
              % Rotate a marker around the circle to show angular speed
              \fill[red] ({0.5*cos(\i)}, {0.5*sin(\i)}) circle (0.05); % Marker

              % Calculate time, rotation in radians, and cycles
              \pgfmathsetmacro{\time}{\i / 36} % time in seconds
              \pgfmathsetmacro{\rotationRadians}{\i * (pi/180)} % rotation in radians
              \pgfmathsetmacro{\rotationCycles}{\i / 360} % rotation in cycles

              % Display text at the bottom using makebox and strut to prevent vertical movement
              \node[anchor=north] at (0,-1.2) {
                \makebox[\widthof{Time (s)  = 99.99}][l]{\strut Time (s)  = \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=2]{\time}}};
              \node[anchor=north] at (0,-1.5) {
                \makebox[\widthof{Rotation (rad)  = 99.99}][l]{\strut Rotation (rad)  = \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=2]{\rotationRadians}}};
              \node[anchor=north] at (0,-1.8) {
                \makebox[\widthof{Cycles  = 9.99}][l]{\strut Cycles  = \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=2]{\rotationCycles}}};
            \end{tikzpicture}
          }
        \end{animateinline}
      \end{column}
    \end{columns}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}


You could add \path (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1); to avoid size changes when the red dot reaches the top of the circle.

You could use a tikz matrix or similar to align your equations.

Do you think you could maybe combine them into an answer to demonstrate?

If you can narrow your question down to a single problem, I could try to answer.

See the amended post. I look forward to your answer...

I would suggest to use some kind of table, either a tikz matrix or a simple tabular:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{pgfmath} % For calculations
\usepackage{calc}    % For width calculations

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[fragile]
    \frametitle{Rotating Yellow Circle Example}
    \begin{columns}
      \begin{column}{0.43\textwidth}
        Text for signal description and other explanations. 
        
        Here is an animation of a yellow circle rotating about its center to demonstrate angular speed.
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{0.57\textwidth}\centering
        \begin{animateinline}[controls={play,stop,step},loop]{12}
          \multiframe{36}{i=0+10}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \path (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
                          \fill[yellow] (0,0) circle (0.5); % Circle at the origin
                          
                          % Rotate a marker around the circle to show angular speed
                          \fill[red] ({0.5*cos(\i)}, {0.5*sin(\i)}) circle (0.05); % Marker
            
            
              % Calculate time, rotation in radians, and cycles
              \pgfmathsetmacro{\time}{\i / 36} % time in seconds
              \pgfmathsetmacro{\rotationRadians}{\i * (pi/180)} % rotation in radians
              \pgfmathsetmacro{\rotationCycles}{\i / 360} % rotation in cycles

              % Display text at the bottom using makebox and strut to prevent vertical movement
              \node[anchor=north] at (-0.1,-1.2) {
                \begin{tabular}{rcp{2cm}}
                  Time (s) & = & \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=2]{\time}\\
                  Rotation (rad) & = & \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=2]{\rotationRadians}\\
                  Cycles &  =  & \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=2]{\rotationCycles}\\
               \end{tabular}
               };
            \end{tikzpicture}
          }
        \end{animateinline}
      \end{column}
    \end{columns}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}


